# Book about a boy who's kidnapped by an alien after getting in a car accident

Tags: story-identification, books

The story begins with a father and son on a night trip in a car when they encounter an accident caused by something hitting their vehicle. The son survives the accident, but instead of the police helping, a stranger arrives and takes the boy away. This stranger then reveals to the boy that he is an alien disguised as a human. The alien's spaceship is disguised as an ice cream truck, which can go transparent and cool down to avoid detection by thermal imaging. At the end of the story, the alien takes the boy to his planet, where there's a machine that transforms the boy into a lizard-like creature, presumably to blend in with the alien society.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  What age group is this aimed at?  A child protagonist and an ice cream truck vehicle make it sound like a children's book, but it sounds like a downer ending.